# Running ssh/netcat in the background

Tags: ssh, bash, netcat

I'm trying to run a network throughput test between an OS X and a Linux host. I'd like to be able to measure the sustained throughput from the Linux host to the OS X host over time. I'd like to wrap this up into a single script so that I can easily run it as I make changes to the network.

My approach so far has been to start netcat on the OS X host listening on a port (`nc -l -k 20000 > /dev/null`). Then I'll start netcat on the Linux host and have it send data to the OS X host (`ssh <Linux host> 'dd if=/dev/zero | nc <OS X host> 20000 2>&1'`). After that I'll run `netstat -i 1` to measure the throughput and log it to a file.

This all works great when I open 3 terminal windows and run these commands in the foreground. However, when I try to run either of the netcat commands in the background, the ssh process exits. I've tried using `&` and `-f` to background the ssh process.

Here is what the full script looks like so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit

nc -l -k 20000 > /dev/null &
LISTEN_PID=$!

ssh <linux host> 'dd if=/dev/zero | nc <os x host> 20000 2>&1' &
SEND_PID=$!

echo "Listen: ${LISTEN_PID}, Send: ${SEND_PID}"

netstat -i 1
```

Comment: How are you authenticating SSH? Password or ssh key?

Comment: I'm using an ssh key

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to use `nohup`

http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've tried using nohup as well. When I do that it exits with an error.

`$ nohup ssh <linux host> 'dd if=/dev/zero | nc <os x host> 20000'`
`appending output to nohup.out`
`$ echo $?`
`127`

Comment: @BrianJohn I've tried the exact same command and it works as expected. Then again, even without the nohup, it works as well...

Answer (score 0):

You might use `screen -d script.sh` to start the script with `screen` in detached mode.